# If two tangents can be drawn to distinct branches of hyperbola $x^2-\frac{y^2}{4}=1$ from the point $(a,a^2)$, then pick the options

Tags: quadratics, conic-sections

> $ a\in (-2,0)$
>
> $a\in (0,2)$
>
> $a\in (-\infty, -2)$
>
> $a\in (\infty, 2)$

The equation for tangent is

$$a^2=ma \pm \sqrt{m^2-4}$$

$$m^2-4=a^4+m^2a^2-2ma^3$$

$$m^2(1-a^2)+2ma^3-(4+a^4)=0$$

For two distinct values

$$a^6+(1-a^2)(a^4+4)>0$$

$$a^4-4a^2+4>0$$
$$(a^2-2)^2>0$$

So $a>\sqrt 2$ and $a<-\sqrt 2$

But this doesn’t match with any of the given options. What’s am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your last line you should get $(a^2-2)^2 \gt 0$ which is always true.

Comment: @Tavish yes it was a typo, but that still doesn’t solve the problem

Comment: What is the answer given? I guess all the choices are correct.

Comment: @Tavish it is a miscellaneous problem, I don’t really know the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve drawn the wrong conclusion from the last inequality. The square of any real number is nonnegative, so for any $a\ne\pm\sqrt2$, $(a^2-2)^2\gt0$.

The more fundamental problem with your approach to a solution, though, is that you’re looking at the wrong condition. You’re looking for points on the parabola $y=x^2$ though which two tangents can be drawn, but two tangents can be drawn to a hyperbola through any point that lies between its branches except along its asymptotes (and even there, if you consider the asymptotes to be tangents at infinity). The only two points on the parabola that aren’t in between the hyperbola’s branches are its two points of intersection with it, corresponding to $a=\pm\sqrt2$. What you really need to consider instead is where the points of tangency lie. Since this hyperbola’s branches lie on either side of the $y$-axis, this means that the $x$-coordinates of the points of contact should have opposite signs.

The extension of the chord of contact is the polar of $(a,a^2)$, namely $$ax-{a^2y\over4}=1.$$ Find the intersections of this line with the hyperbola and then find the conditions on $a$ for the product (or ratio, whichever gives you a simpler expression to work with) of their $x$-coordinates to be negative. You’ll need to take some care with values of $a$ for which either expression vanishes since by examining the product or ratio you’re effectively using the reciprocal of one or the other of them.

Comment: So the equation I got for $x$ was $x^2(a^4-4a^2)+8ax-4-a^4=0$. For the product to be negative, $\frac{4+a^4}{a^4-4a^2}>0$ and using the wavy curve method I got $a\in (-2,0) \cup (2,\infty)$. What’s wrong here now?

Comment: @Aditya I don’t know what the “wavy curve method is,” but something clearly went wrong in your calculations. The last expression is an even function of $a$, so the region in which it is positive must perforce be symmetric about the origin. The numerator is always positive, so the sign depends only on the denominator. That factors into $a^2(a^2-4)$, so we must have $a^2-4\gt0$ (and, of course, $a\ne0$, but that’s subsumed). That fits geometrically, as that’s the part of the parabola that lies above the two asymptotes, which is where tangents to the hyperbola meet separate branches.

Comment: @Aditya Note, too, that you don’t have to solve for $x$ explicitly. The product of the roots can be extracted from the quadratic equation via Vieta’s formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the asymptotes of $x^2-\frac{y^2}{4}=1$ are $y=\pm 2x$, which intersect $y=x^2$, the curve of $(a,a^2)$ at $x=\pm2$.

Geometrically, for any point $(a,a^2)$ above the asymptotes, there is only one tangent line that can be drawn to either branch of the hyperbola, which can also be seen from that $a^2=ma \pm \sqrt{m^2-4}$ has only one root $m$ for each branch for $|a| >2$.

Thus, the options are $a\in(-\infty,-2)$ and $a\in (2,\infty)$.

Comment: If there is only one root of $m$, then how does it satisfy the given conditions?

Comment: @Aditya - to clarify, it is one root for each branch, which is the given condition

Comment: How can you tell it’s for each branch?

Comment: @Aditya - for example, if $a=3$, you get $m=\frac52$ for the branch $a^2=m a+ \sqrt{m^2-4}$ and $m=\frac{17}4$ for the branch $a^2=m a-\sqrt{m^2-4}$

Comment: I know this seems wrong, but could you please check my comment on the previous answer? I tried his method but ended up with the same answer

Comment: @Aditya - it seems okay, although I’m always leery of squaring the equation which requires extra validation of the solutions at the end

Comment: Yeah but I didn’t get $(-\infty, -2)$

Comment: Which equation is it that you think is getting squared?

Comment: @amd - the quartic one in Aditya’s comment

Comment: That’s just the intersection of a line with the hyperbola. There are no extraneous solutions introduced there. An excess of caution isn’t a bad thing, but it’s unnecessary here.

Comment: @amd - glad to hear it is okay